# Почему в запросе инициализированная переменная имеет значение NULL?

Tags: sql-server

Есть следующий sql скрипт

```
DECLARE @position INT
SET @position = 788

Select
  @position as ParameterId
Into #temp_table
From table
```

Все работает: значение `ParameterId` равно указанному значению, но если добавить между объявлением и инициализацией переменной и самим запросом проверку существования таблицы и удаление ее:

```
DECLARE @position INT
SET @position = 788

IF OBJECT_ID('#assemblies', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #assemblies
GO

Select
  @position as ParameterId
Into #temp_table
From table
```

то тогда в запросе `ParameterId` имеет значение `null`. Подскажите почему так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все дело в ключевом слове `GO`, которая не является командой TSQL, но распознается программами sqlcmd и osql, а также редактором кода в среде Среда SQL Server Management Studio. Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)

> Область видимости локальных (пользовательских) переменных ограничена
>   пакетом, и к ним нельзя обращаться после команды GO.